# Nginx + Zend Framework 2 + Run multiple websites with different domain from the same codebase

Tags: nginx, centos, zend-framework2

I have a modular Zend Framework application which I would like to use as a basis for several websites with different domains, i.e.:

- mywebsite.com
- mydifferentwebsite.com
- mythirdwebsite.com

I want to run all of these websites from the same codebase and the same server. I would like to change different settings such as styles or available pages based on the hostname.

Currently this is how I am getting the hostname:

```
$requestSiteUrl = $this->serviceLocator->get('URLRequest')->getServer('HTTP_HOST');
```

However I am not sure how reliable this would be. Is there a better way to find out which website the request is coming from?

Here is an example Nginx config I am using for different websites on the server:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite.com;

        root /var/www/mywebsite/public;
        index index.php;

        server_tokens off;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV develop;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/php/mywebsite_php_errors.log";
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
$requestSiteUrl = $this->serviceLocator->get('URLRequest')->getServer('HTTP_HOST');
```

Is another way of doing:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

(but obviously works better when the variable isn't set). So yes it's a fine way of finding out which domain nginx thinks was requested. Technically there is a security hole if:

- Someone just modifies the `Host` header on their request.
- If you have the sites on different IP addresses and someone edits their hosts file to have the 'wrong' IP for a server, and then makes a request to that 'wrong' IP address.

Then you could have the wrong site name come up.

If all of your sites are on the same IP then there's not much you could do about that spoofing. If they're all on separate IP addresses, and you setup Nginx to use one `server` per host, and they're just listening on their allocated IP address, then you could change to using

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

or the Zend equivalent.

That would then only give you the server name as defined by the `server_name` entry in your config file, and be unspoofable.

So long as you aren't making any security be dependent on having the correct server name, then you shouldn't have a problem. i.e. when people login to one site, they shouldn't be also logged into the other sites, as the session name should be unique per site.